# Nginx proxy_pass based on file extension and query string

Tags: nginx, querystring, lua

I need to proxy_pass static assets (.js .css) based on file extension and query strings.

For example:

domain.com/foo.css - go to upstream1
domain.com/foo.css?V=1234 - go to upstream2

Reason is I have a 3 server setup - a router, an application server and a static server. I would like any request with clean url domain.com/foo.cs to go to upstream1 (where my static server is configured). And any request that has query string url domain.com/foo.css?V=1234 to go to upstream2 (where my application server is configured).

Maybe it can be done using http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html).

```
map $arg_v $node {
    default        upstream1;
    "~^[0-9]+$"    upstream2;
}


server {

    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;

    location ~ \.(css|js)$ {
        proxy_pass http://$node;
    }

 }
```

Comment: Hi Xavier,

This does seem to sort of work. However, it just sends requests to upstream1. When I try to request domain.com/test.js?V=asdf or domain.com/test.js?V=1234 it always proxies to upstream1.

I guess I should update the regex ?

Comment: @RadoslavStefanov There's no reason that test.js?V=1234 would be proxied to upstream1. How do you test it, and what's your full config ? If you have not only digits then yes you will need to update the regex.

Comment: I just applied this config for testing and requested domain.com/bla.js?V=1234

map $arg_v $node {
    default        192.168.10.1;
    "~^[0-9]+$"    192.168.10.2;
}


server {

    listen 192.168.10.80:80;
    server_name domain.com;

    location ~ \.(css|js)$ {
        proxy_pass http://node;
    }

 }

This actually gives me an error:

nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "node" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test:13

Comment: @RadoslavStefanov Oh yeah, typo in my post. Use `$node` not `node`.